# Mysql query to see if a booking will conflict with another booking.

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table which stores a bunch of books. Customers can book appointments at for any time during the day. I want to make sure that a booking doesnt already exist that will conflict with the new booking.

So I want to find the booking on that date and check that the start and end times dont overlap. I tried doing this with a sub select query to get the bookings from that day and then see if those times overlapped but it didnt seem to be working.

Here is the query I am using. (Status and active are some other fields I need). I find the relevant dates and then see if 8am is between those results individual start/end times or is 9.40am also falls between start/end times.

```
SELECT event_date, starttime, endtime, status, active 
FROM (SELECT event_date, starttime, endtime, status, active FROM bookings WHERE event_date='2013-07-21' AND status != 'cancelled' AND active !=0 LIMIT 1) AS q1
WHERE ('8:00:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime) AND ('9:40:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime)
```

Is this the best method to use? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if one range overlaps another it's easier to think first when it won't overlap and then reverse the condition. It's obvious that:

> Two ranges (A,B) *don't* overlap if A starts after B ends, or if A ends before B starts.

Turning this to SQL you get the following condition for finding an overlapping range:

```
... WHERE NOT ('8:00:00' > q1.endtime OR '9:40:00' < q1.starttime)
```

If you want you can rewrite that as:

```
... WHERE q1.endtime > '8:00:00' AND q1.starttime < '9:40:00'
```

This way you handle all the corner cases, like one interval completely containing the other.

Answer (score 4):

`WHERE ('8:00:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime) AND ('9:40:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime)`

This implies that the new appointment (8 to 9:40) lies ENTIRELY INSIDE an already existing appt.  Instead, you want (I think) to see if either the start OR end of the appt coincides with another one:

`WHERE ('8:00:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime) OR ('9:40:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime)`

Also, I'm pretty sure that inner select is unnecessary.  I believe this will have the same effect:

```
SELECT TOP 1 event_date, starttime, endtime, status, active
FROM bookings 
WHERE event_date='2013-07-21' 
    AND status != 'cancelled' 
    AND active != 0
    AND (('8:00:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime)
        OR ('9:40:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime))
-- if you get a row, then there is a conflicting appt.
```

Comment: I tried that but it still wasnt giving me results but the other option below worked in my case. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the same problem and i used the posted solution but there is another bug that i found if the previous record was lie in the new record as example

The record in the database is 
starttime 8:30:00
endtime   9:00:00

In this case the record will be added as no matching rows will be found with this

```
SELECT TOP 1 event_date, starttime, endtime, status, active
FROM bookings 
WHERE event_date='2013-07-21' 
    AND status != 'cancelled' 
    AND active != 0
    AND (('8:00:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime)
        OR ('9:40:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime))
```

to fix this issue you need check if the start time or end time it self lies between your new entry like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 event_date, starttime, endtime, status, active
FROM bookings 
WHERE event_date='2013-07-21' 
    AND status != 'cancelled' 
    AND active != 0
    AND (('8:00:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime)
        OR ('9:40:00' BETWEEN q1.starttime AND q1.endtime)
        OR (q1.starttime BETWEEN '8:00:00' AND '9:40:00')
        OR (q1.endtime BETWEEN 8:00:00' AND '9:40:00')
)
```